H1 to H6 HTML tag not working as expected in LWC
I have created below LWC and I have used HTML tags H1 to H6. When I run the LWC All the heading tags will be rendered as same. When I debugged and found that the app.css file overrides the H1 to H6 style. Is this default behaviour or it is a bug?
HTML:
<template>
        <h1>This is a Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>This is a Heading 2</h2>
        <h3>This is a Heading 3</h3>
        <h4>This is a Heading 4</h4>
        <h5>This is a Heading 5</h5>
        <h6>This is a Heading 6</h6>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class DataBinding extends LightningElement {}

Output:



The app.css file overrides the H1 to H6 tag css that's why not showing the heading tag style in lwc.
Below is the Salesforce Support response,

Thank you for your patience as we reviewed your inquiry regarding the
rendering of heading tags (h1 to h6) in your Lightning Web Component
(LWC).
I understand your concern about the heading tags displaying the same
style when rendered. After investigating, I can confirm that this
behavior is expected due to the default styling applied in the
Salesforce Lightning framework. The app.css file indeed resets the
styles for heading elements (h1 to h6) to maintain a consistent look
and feel across applications.
As referenced in our documentation, all heading sizes are set to the
base size, with margins and padding reset to zero. This design choice
ensures accessibility and allows for flexibility in how headings are
utilized based on the context of your components.
For your reference, I’m sharing the documentation:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/text/
If you would like to customize the appearance of these heading tags,
you can do so by adding specific styles in your component's CSS file
to override the default styles. Salesforce recommends using the
Salesforce Lightning Design System (SLDS) for styling to ensure
consistency and best practices. However, if needed, you can also use
custom CSS for additional customization.


Suggest you remove the term "properly". LWCs explicitly use SLDS and that design system made that choice and supplied e.g. slds-text-heading_large to alter heading styling.
